# How to determine result type of numpy array operation in advance?

Tags: python, numpy

In order to create an empty array for some results, I need to know the resulting `dtype` for a certain operation (e.g. multiply) when doing the operation based on two other arrays.

How to determine resulting `dtype` of a numpy array operation in advance?

If `a` and `b` are the argument arrays, I can for example determine the resulting `dtype` of the multiplication (`*`) by making to zero values (`0`) and doing a trial operation, like:

```
dtype=(a.dtype.type(0) * b.dtype.type(0)).dtype
```

However, it seems a little award... or maybe I do this the wrong way around...

So using the `result_type`, given in the accepted answer, the code can be like:

```
dtype=numpy.result_type(a, b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `numpy.result_type()`, in numpy >= 1.6.0

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html